# Restrict MVC method to accept only AJAX calls

Tags: java, ajax

How can we restrict MVC method to accept only AJAX calls in java?

I am using 'Spring' as MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. An "AJAX call" is just a normal HTTP request.